# Are ZeroMQ inproc:// based sockets experimental?

Tags: zeromq

After a decade of using ZeroMQ I noticed a foot note in the zmq_socket API docs that states:

> ZMQ_PAIR sockets are designed for inter-thread communication across the zmq_inproc(7) transport and do not implement functionality such as auto-reconnection. ZMQ_PAIR sockets are considered experimental and may have other missing or broken aspects.

http://api.zeromq.org/2-1:zmq-socket

However, the zmq_inproc API docs doesn't mention any form of "experimental" status in regards to zmq_inproc itself. Should I interpret this to only being relevant to network socket based ZMQ_PAIR abstractions?

Comment: Yes, that seems like the correct interpretation.

Comment: v2 is very old now, v4.3 does not mention experimental. http://api.zeromq.org/4-3:zmq-socket